# DNS and non-root site

Tags: dns, server

I've set up a Zope/Plone web server on 10.10.10.10:8080. I will have several sites hosted on this server. Each site will be located below the root e.g. `10.10.10.10:8080/Mysite1`, `10.10.10.10:8080/Yoursite2`, `10.10.10.10:8080/Theirsite3`, etc.

With DNS on a Win Server 2008 R2, I've tried creating an A record for 10.10.10.10 to point to mysites.domain.org and then use a CNAME record to point to one of the non-root sites. i.e.

```
A record -          mysites.domain.org. IN A 10.10.10.10
CNAME record -      Theirsite3.domain.org IN CNAME mysites.domain.org:8080/theirsite3
```

My goal is to have one IP for the server and to redirect its '10.10.10.10/sites' to a subdomain name. I'm not quite sure how to frame the question, I will clarify and update my question as needed.

Is DNS capable of handling this? or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- RTFM CNAME RR definition:

  Theirsite3.domain.org IN CNAME mysites.domain.org:8080/theirsite3

is just an **extremely bad** definition.

```
Theirsite3 IN CNAME mysites
```

or

```
Theirsite3.domain.org. IN CNAME mysites.domain.org.
```

in domain.org zone definition will work

- All **sites** (presence and mapping to local FS) must be defined in http-server config. How to do this configuration is heavy *server-dependent* and I know nothing about IIS

Comment: I think I may be heading in the right direction.  Multiple IPs per NIC?  [Config Ubuntu 6.10 NIC with multi-IP addresses](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=7949)

Comment: @Davidm - Multiple sites perfectly work on single shared IP